# Facebook app showing null reference exception

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-apps, facebook-sdk-3.0

I tried out this sample facebook app using MVC,

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-facebook-birthday-app

I encountered null reference exception at,

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [FacebookAuthorize("email", "friends_birthday")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(FacebookContext context)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await context.Client.GetCurrentUserAsync<MyAppUser>();
            var friendsWithUpcomingBirthdays = user.Friends.Data.OrderBy(friend =>
            {
               //some code
          } 
          }
          }
          }
```

**null reference exception at**

```
      var friendsWithUpcomingBirthdays = user.Friends.Data.OrderBy(friend =>
```

The FB account I used to develop this app has added no friends yet,

Is that the problem?.. because this method

```
             await context.Client.GetCurrentUserAsync<MyAppUser>();
```

returned friend--"null",

Is it the reason for it to throw null reference exception at that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In found out the solution,

Its because there is no friend in that fb account.

I added a friend I tested, It worked fine.

Comment: The real solution, however, is to check for null values. If someone else uses this and they have no friends it'll still crash.

Comment: @BuildStarted yeah thank you for your comment. I will look into it in checking null values.